# Array of Jpanel with a button and a checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jcheckbox

I have an array of button that displays images after image query. Now I am trying to add a checkbox under each button so user can check if that's a relevant image. I was going to have an array of Jpanel where each Jpanel consist of one button and checkbox but I don't know how to incorporate all the components in my code.This is what I have so far:

```
resultPanel = new JPanel[10];
resultPanel[10].add(relevantFB);
resultPanel[10].add(button);

for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
 button[i] = new JButton(newIcon);
 relevantFB[i] = new JCheckBox();
 relevantFB[i].setText("Relevant Image" + i);
 panelBottom1.add(button[i]);
 button[i].addActionListener(new IconButtonHandler(i, newIcon));
 relevantFB[i].addActionListener(new IconCheckboxHandler(i, newIcon));
 buttonOrder[i] = i;
 checkboxOrder[i]=i;
}
```

Comment: Quit SHOUTING when you ask a question!!

Comment: and for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1):

For that you mustn't create JPanel for each pair(checkbox+button). You must create one Panel, and place components with help of layout manager. In is work for **LayoutManager**.

You can use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for that purposes. In next example I create 5 buttons and 5 checkboxes under buttons :

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

public Example() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    JButton btns[] = new JButton[5];
    JCheckBox chboxes[] = new JCheckBox[5];

    c.gridx = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<btns.length;i++){
        btns[i] = new JButton(""+i);
        getContentPane().add(btns[i],c);
        c.gridx++;
    }

    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<chboxes.length;i++){
        chboxes[i] = new JCheckBox(""+i);
        getContentPane().add(chboxes[i],c);
        c.gridx++;
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String...strings ){
    Example e = new Example();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks @alex2410, This helps a lot but I have buttons that have thumbnails in them in which if I set up my layout as 4 by 5 matrix, I don't know how to get my image icon with the buttons. `code` for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) { ImageIcon newIcon; newIcon = new ImageIcon("path" + i + ".jpg");if(newIcon != null){button[i] = new JButton(newIcon);
                         getContentPane().add(button[i],resultPanel);
                        relevantFB[i] = new JCheckBox("Relevant Image");getContentPane().add(relevantFB[i],panelBottom1);`code` sorry for the mess of showing my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel with a GridBagLayout. Put buttons on the first row an checkboxes beneath.

--Edit--

Here is some code. This is assuming you have n icons in an array `icon`. Unlike you I've assumed the icons are numbered staring at 0.

```
    JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel() ;
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout() ;
    resultPanel.setLayout( gbl );
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints() ;

    JButton[] button = new JButton[n] ; ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ) {
        button[i] = new JButton( new ImageIcon( "path"+(i+1)+".jpg" ) ); }
        button[i].addActionListener(new IconButtonHandler(i+1, icon[i]));
        constraints.gridx = i ;
        constraints.gridy = 0 ;
        resultPanel.Add( button[i], constraints ) ; }

    JCheckBox[] relevantFB = new JCheckBox[n] ; ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ) {
        relevantFB[i] = new JCheckBox();
        relevantFB[i].setText("Relevant Image" + (i+1));
        relevantFB[i].addActionListener(new IconCheckboxHandler(i+1, icon[i]));
        constraints.gridx = i ;
        constraints.gridy = 1 ;
        resultPanel.add( relevantFB[i], constraints ) ; }
```